# Weird behaviour with conditional operator in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-operator, nullable, value-type

This has me pretty stumped. Maybe I'm too tired right now.

```
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
    Rectangle cropArea = inputArea == null ? rectangle : inputArea.Value;

    if (inputArea == null)
        cropArea = rectangle;
```

inputArea is a nullable Rectangle, which in my particular case is null.

The first two statements yields a cropArea initialized to 0. The second, however, yields the correct cropArea based on the image width and height. Have I misunderstood anything with the conditional operator? It seems it does not return rectangle when inputArea = null? Is there any quirks when working with value types?

EDIT: Alright, I should have tried this first: restarted VS. It seems the debugger lied to me, or something. Anyway, works now. Thanks.

Comment: I thought about leaving it as a hint to anyone else that restarting VS can always solve unexpected problems. What do you think?

Comment: Who the hell downvoted this question??? It is a perfectly valid question exposing a horrible bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: As an aside, note that you could use the null coalescing operator instead of the conditional operator here: croparea = inputArea ?? rectangle;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a nasty bug in Visual Studio debug mode which is fooling you:

[image]

Now <kbd>F10</kbd> to step over this line and you get:

[image]

On the console correct values are printed.

WTF.

Comment: Did you try Nullable<Rectangle>

Comment: @JeremySpouken, for which variable?

Comment: @JeremySpouken: That’s equivalent to `Rectangle?`.

Comment: Interesting. I typed the same code into VS and I get the correct values (in both DEBUG and RELEASE mode)...

Comment: @Timwi, what is the exact version number of VS you are using and the OS? For me it's `10.0.30319.1 RTMRel` running on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: @HiTech Magic, do you understand what a nullable type means in .NET and what's the use of `System.Nullable<T>`? From your comments I get the impression that you don't. I would recommend you reading the relevant section from the documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

Comment: @Darin: Same here but 32-bit — that may well make the difference. Thanks for digging :)

Comment: @whomever cares: Quite right. It is System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle that is not Nullable (i.e. Silverlight). I will try and add lots of pleases etc to ensure everyone does not react so violently to my comments in future :)

Comment: @HiTech Magic, now that makes things clear :-) Also if you have read the question more carefully you would have noticed that he is using `inputArea.Value` and there's no `Value` property defined in `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` class as well as a constructor taking 4 integer parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rectangle cropArea = (!inputArea.HasValue) ? rectangle : inputArea.Value;
```

Comment: Now why the spam on *my* thread fellas :)
@Hitech
            Rectangle? inputArea = null;
            Nullable<Rectangle> inputArea2 = null;

@TimWi - now why the downvote .. was just trying to help the OP out?

Comment: +1 because I made a mistake on your post and started a small flame war. Turns out it is only the Silverlight Rectange class that is not nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears correct. The conditional expression (or conditional operator, or *originally called the ternary operator*... everyone happy now? :)) should be interchangeable with if/else statements.

```
Rectangle cropArea = inputArea == null ? rectangle : inputArea.Value;
```

should be exactly the same as:

```
Rectangle cropArea;
if (inputArea == null)
{
    cropArea = rectangle;
}
else
{
    cropArea = inputArea.Value;
}
```

(in fact they should generate the same IL code).

**Trace through with the debugger and see if anything jumps out at you.**

Comment: Please don’t call the conditional operator “the ternary operator”. I’ve edited your answer to correct this, I hope you don’t mind.

Comment: @Timwi: You need to complain to the jQuery site as well now. They also call it the ternary operator (different language, same operator) :) http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/conditional-code/

Answer (score 0):

So are you saying that when `inputArea` is `null`, without the `if` statement you get a rectangle initialized to something else than the image size? I just tried running that and it works fine. Make sure that `image` has a size and that `inputArea` is actually `null`.

Comment: Yes, all of which had seemed very weird, until I realized visual studio lied to me. See my edit.

Answer (score -1):

What the hell?

```
Rectangle rectangle = ...;
Rectangle cropArea;
if (inputArea == null)
    cropArea = rectangle;
else
    cropArea = inputArea.Value;

if (inputArea == null)
    cropArea = rectangle;
```

Why have the second if? It's totally and entirely redundant. The scenario in which cropArea might still be null or zero is if inputArea.Value is null/zero, since you didn't check for that (only if inputArea is null).